# How to read values from `defaults` in swift?

Tags: swift, macos

### Target

I want to control the app's behavior through command line tool, like enabling some testing features. Then I thought maybe I can use `defaults tool` to set a configuration that app can read it.

### The following is what I tried:

#### In command line

```
defaults write com.my.app enableFeature2 -bool true
```

#### In app

```
let userDefaults = UserDefaults.standard
userDefaults.addSuite("com.my.app")
let val = userDefaults.value(forKey: "enableFeature2")

print(val) // got a nil
```

#### Expected usage

```
let bEnableFeature2 = (val as? Bool) ?? false
if bEnableFeature2 {
     enableFeature2();
}
```

#### Actual

```
The `val` from userDefaults is `nil`
```

In app's UserDefaults, it seems it unable to locate the plist and read a nil from it . I think I may do something wrong or miss something.

After the `defaults` command is issued, a plist file is generated at `~/Library/Preferences/` named com.my.app.plist, whose content is simply `Root { enableFeature2/Boolean/YES }`.

How should I bridge the interaction between command-line and app?

--

#### Others

- My testing build is launched via XCode
- Located in `~/Library/Developer/XCode/Derived/{APP_LONG_NAME}/`
- `com.my.app` is not my application domain, I am a module in application so I need an another domain name.

Comment: Unrelated but never use `value(forKey` with `UserDefaults` unless you know what KVC is and why you really need it. There is `bool(forKey` and many other dedicated methods.

Comment: I am unfamiliar to UserDefaults so I use the API to only check the existence. Now I will start to use the typed API. Thanks.

Comment: `object(forKey:)`(or even better `bool(forKey:)`) is the method to get something from `UserDefaults`. `value(forKey:)` is generic method of `NSObject` to access its properties.

Comment: Is this actually about iOS, or just MacOS?

Comment: @JeroenJK you are right it is macOS only. I removed iOS tag.